# How to get first item from a java.util.Set?

Tags: java, set

I have a **Set** instance:

```
Set<String> siteIdSet = (Set<String>) pContext.getParent().getPropertyValue(getCatalogProperties().getSitesPropertyName());
```

The `pContext.getParent().getPropertyValue()` is out-of-the-box code upon which I don't have any control to modify.

### Requirement:

I wanted to get the *first* default element out of it (always).  However, I couldn't find a method `get(index)` like in an `ArrayList`.

Hence, right now, I am doing like this.

```
for (Iterator<String> it = siteIdSet.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    siteId = it.next();
    break;
}
```

Is there any (other) **efficient way** (short and better) of achieving this?

Comment: A Set doesn't have a first item. The iteration over all the elements in the set has a first item.

Comment: You have to put it into a LinkedHashset for the order.

Comment: @Java_Alert but how do you get the first element in this case?

Comment: Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
}

Comment: This way you can maintain the order in set.

Comment: @Java_Alert I already have that in the question.

Comment: You don't have insertion order.you can get that by LinkHashSet.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar There isn't likely a better way to do what you ask (as it is very rare that a user would ever want to get just a single element from a `Set`). The only **shorter** way I can think of to do this is to use a `for-each` loop instead of the `for` loop you have. It's exactly the same (functionally), but is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Pretty much all of the answers are wrong in the special case where you have a set with exactly one item. In that case there is certainly a "first" (and also a "last") item in the set. It's a shame that you have to create an iterator to access this.

Comment: [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical *set* abstraction.

In [Set Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory), "a "set" is a collection of distinct objects, considered as an object in its own right." - [[Wikipedia - Set]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29).

Mathematically, elements in sets are not individualised. Their only identity is derived from their presence in the set. Therefore, there is no point in getting the "first" element in a set, as conceptually such a task is illogical.

There may be no point to getting the "first" element from a set, but if all you need is to get one single object from a set (with no guarantees as to which object that is) you can do the following:

```
for(String aSiteId: siteIdSet) {
    siteId = aSiteId;
    break;
}
```

This is a slightly shorter way (than the method you posted) to get the "first" object of a `Set`, however since an Iterator is still being created (under the hood) it does not grant any performance benefit.

Comment: Yet, it has a practical use : sometimes you need some element (any one) from a set.

Comment: Good idea, when developing, we usually miss the break point and rather continue finding the solution to get the first index

Answer (score 126):

This will return the first element

```
set.iterator().next();
```

Comment: through java.util.NoSuchElementException when set is empty.

Comment: Use ```Assert.notEmpty(set);``` before getting first element.

Answer (score 49):

Or, using Java8+:

```
Object firstElement = set.stream().findFirst().get();
```

And then you can do stuff with it straight away:

```
set.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(<doStuffHere>);
```

Or, if you want to provide an alternative in case the element is missing (my example returns new default string):

```
set.stream().findFirst().orElse("Empty string");
```

You can even throw an exception if the first element is missing:

```
set.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new MyElementMissingException("Ah, blip, nothing here!"));
```

Kudos to `Alex Vulaj` for prompting me to provide more examples beyond the initial grabbing of the first element.

Comment: To piggy back on this - you could change your `.get()` to an `.orElse()` if you want to provide a default value in the event that `outcome` is empty.

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

Call [`SortedSet::first`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#first%28%29)

Move elements, and call `first()`.

```
new TreeSet<String>( 
    pContext.getParent().getPropertyValue( … )   // Transfer elements from your `Set` to this new `TreeSet`, an implementation of the `SortedSet` interface. 
)
.first()
```

## `Set` Has No Order

As others have said, a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) by definition has no order. Therefore asking for the “first” element has no meaning.

Some implementations of `Set` have an order such as the order in which items were added. That unofficial order may be available via the [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). But that order is accidental and not guaranteed. If you are lucky, the implementation backing your `Set` may indeed be a `SortedSet`.

**CAVEAT:** If order is critical, **do not rely on such behavior**. If reliability is not critical, such undocumented behavior might be handy. If given a `Set` you have no other viable alternative, so trying this may be better than nothing.

```
Object firstElement = mySet.iterator().next();
```

To directly address the Question… No, not really any shorter way to get first element from iterator while handling the possible case of an empty Set. However, I would prefer an `if` test for `isEmpty` rather than the Question’s `for` loop.

```
if ( ! mySet.isEmpty() ) {
    Object firstElement = mySet.iterator().next();
)
```

## Use `SortedSet`

If you care about maintaining a sort order in a `Set`, use a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) implementation. Such implementations include:

- [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).
- [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html).
- In [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava), the [`SortedSetMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SortedSetMultimap.html)  class returns a `SortedSet` from its [`asMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SortedSetMultimap.html#asMap()) method.

## Use `NavigableSet`

The `SortedSet` interface was succeeded by the [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) interface. This newer interface adds features. The same two bundled classes that implement `SortedSet`, `TreeSet` & `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, also implement `NavigableSet`.

## Use `LinkedHashSet` For Insertion-Order

If all you need is to remember elements in the order they were added to the `Set` use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

To quote the doc, this class…

> maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).

Answer (score 9):

Set is a unique collection of items. So there is no notion of first element. If you want items in the sorted order, you can use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) from which you can retrieve the first element using [TreeSet#first()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#first%28%29).

Comment: The `pContext.getParent().getPropertyValue()` method always returns `Set<String>`, hence I don't have an option of changing that to a `TreeSet`.  Moreover, I don't want the contents of the `Set` to be _sorted_.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar, As your method return Set, You can convert Set to ArrayList.

Comment: If you are working at the Set interface level, there is no first element. Iterate the list and use which ever element it gives you first.

Answer (score 3):

`Set` does not enforce ordering. There is no guarantee that you will always get the "first" element even if you use an iterator over a `HashSet` like you have done in the question.

If you need to have predictable ordering, you need to use the [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) implementation. When you iterate over a LinkedHashSet, you will get the elements in the order you inserted. You still need to use an iterator, because having a `get` method in `LinkedHashSet` would need you to use the concrete class everywhere.

Comment: I can't find the `get(index)` method in `LinkedHashSet` either.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar - access is through the iterator() method

Comment: There is no get method. You need to still use the iterator.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult question I came up against the other day myself. `java.util.LinkedHashSet` maintains a linked list of its contents (addition-ordered by default) but does not provide any accessors. Other structure types will fail to provide O(1) on `add()`, `remove()`, and `contains()`.

You can use a `LinkedHashSet` and get its `iterator()`, grab one element, and discard it. If you don't care too much about speed or memory when doing this frequently to numerous different sets, that is probably your solution... but that seemed wasteful to me.  Plus I had a little extra desired functionality.

I ended up writing my own class, dubbed `RandomAccessLinkedHashSet`, which concurrently maintains a hashtable, a doubly linked list, and an order-irrelevant array. I wrote it to comply with both `Set` and `Deque`, though the Deque implementation is a little sketchy since it will fail to `push()` elements it already contains, a little bit of a stretch for the interface's contract. Maintaining the third structure, the array, is not necessary at all for what you're doing, but it also allows access to a *random* element in the set in whatever capacity you can actually provide a random value.

If you're interested I can provide this source. I haven't `Serialized` it yet but it works great in runtime.

**If you cannot guarantee the type of `Set` provided in any way, then you'll have to stick with the `Iterator` thing.**

Answer (score 3):

As, you mentioned `pContext.getParent().getPropertyValue` return `Set`. You can convert `Set` to `List` to get the first element. Just change your code like:

```
 Set<String> siteIdSet = (Set<String>) pContext.getParent().getPropertyValue(..);
 List<String> siteIdList=new ArrayList<>(siteIdSet);

 String firstItem=siteIdList.get(0);
```

Comment: That's an `O(n)` operation to get an element.

Answer (score 2):

To Access the element you need to get an iterator . But Iterator does not guarantee in a particular order unless it is some Exceptional case. so it is not sure to get the first Element.

Comment: Not exactly true. Some `Iterator` objects for `Set` objects *do* guarantee a particular order. For example, [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) promises to maintain insertion-order. And any `Set` implementing [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) promises a certain order.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Object firstElement = set.toArray()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and found your question here ...

This was my solution:

```
Set<Integer> mySetOfIntegers = new HashSet<Integer>();
/* ... there's at least one integer in the set ... */

Integer iFirstItemInSet = new ArrayList<Integer>(mySetOfIntegers).get(0);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem like a good solution, as this copies every single value from the set into the ArrayList, then only fetches the first one and discards the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in retrieving first element from a Set. If you have such kind of requirement use ArrayList instead of sets. Sets do not allow duplicates. They contain distinct elements.

Comment: There is nothing like first element in a Set. It may return value of the item which you might have not entered first in the set. Still if you want to get he first element , you are going right by using iterator class.

Comment: See  [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set by definition is not ordered.

You probably use wrong collection.

Comment: Not exactly correct. See the [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface which extends `Set`. Bundled with Java 2 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Vector has some handy features:

```
Vector<String> siteIdVector = new Vector<>(siteIdSet);
String first = siteIdVector.firstElement();
String last = siteIdVector.lastElement();
```

But I do agree - this may have unintended consequences, since the underling set is not guaranteed to be ordered.